# Chart.js - different height for X & Y axis?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I have a dynamic chart where using filters, data either comes in or leaves the chart.

Some of my X axis labels are pretty....... long. :) Mostly they fit within the 400px chart but the ones that are very long don't and get truncated.
So currently I have solved that by simply adjusting the chart height itself, so that it fits pretty much any X axis label no matter how short or long it is.

But I've noticed, that with the height change the overall height of the bars (well, the height of everything that's above the X axis labels) also changed, so this means that if a user adds a content to the chart which has a long X axis label, they will get this content in, however the rest of the content that's already in there will visually increase its size.

Is it possible to set a different height for the main part of the chart and for the X axis labels?

Thanks.